# Error creating VM using service account with Compute Instance Admin (beta) IAM role

Tags: google-compute-engine

I creating a VM using a cloud function and both the cloud function and compute instance being instantiated using same Service account(SA). To this SA I have granted `Compute Instance Admin (beta)` IAM role. In the Stack driver logs I am seeing below errors attempting to create VM. I have noticed if I grant `Editor` role to SA I`m able to create VM. I'm not sure what is the issue here. Please advice.

```
**LOG 1** - Compute Engine insert us-central1-a:abc20200408180340 YY@XXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com INVALID_ARGUMENT
full log message - 
    {
     insertId: "50eye6dadjc"  
     logName: "projects/XXXX/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity"  
     operation: {
      id: "operation-1586369020768-5a2cb51f731c4-4c38b6fc-0bb59fb4"   
      last: true   
      producer: "compute.googleapis.com"   
     }
     protoPayload: {
      @type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"   
      authenticationInfo: {
       principalEmail: "YY@XXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com"    
      }
      methodName: "v1.compute.instances.insert"   
      request: {
       @type: "type.googleapis.com/compute.instances.insert"    
      }
      requestMetadata: {
       callerIp: "2600:1900:2001:2::b"    
       callerSuppliedUserAgent: "(gzip),gzip(gfe)"    
       destinationAttributes: {
       }
       requestAttributes: {
       }
      }
      resourceName: "projects/XXXX/zones/us-central1-a/instances/abc20200408180340"   
      serviceName: "compute.googleapis.com"   
      status: {
       code: 3    
       message: "INVALID_ARGUMENT"    
      }
     }
     receiveTimestamp: "2020-04-08T18:03:51.502654357Z"  
     resource: {
      labels: {
       instance_id: "894148589006335762"    
       project_id: "XXXX"    
       zone: "us-central1-a"    
      }
      type: "gce_instance"   
     }
     severity: "ERROR"  
     timestamp: "2020-04-08T18:03:50.428Z"  
    }
**LOG 2** - 2020-04-08 13:03:50.699 CDT compute.instances.insert {"version":"1.2","error":[{"location":"","code":"SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_DENIED","detail_message":""}],"event_timestamp_us":"1586369030699874","actor":{"user":"YY@XXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com"},"resource":{"type":"instance","zone":"us-central1-a","id":"894148589006335762","name":"ba…
full log message -     
    {
     insertId: "6o45gig1jthjep"  
     jsonPayload: {
      actor: {
       user: "YY@XXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com"    
      }
      error: [
       0: {
        code: "SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_DENIED"     
        detail_message: ""     
        location: ""     
       }
      ]
      event_subtype: "compute.instances.insert"   
      event_timestamp_us: "1586369030699874"   
      event_type: "GCE_OPERATION_DONE"   
      operation: {
       id: "8573989519473487634"    
       name: "operation-1586369020768-5a2cb51f731c4-4c38b6fc-0bb59fb4"    
       type: "operation"    
       zone: "us-central1-a"    
      }
      resource: {
       id: "894148589006335762"    
       name: "abc20200408180340"    
       type: "instance"    
       zone: "us-central1-a"    
      }
      trace_id: "operation-1586369020768-5a2cb51f731c4-4c38b6fc-0bb59fb4"   
      version: "1.2"   
     }
     labels: {
      compute.googleapis.com/resource_id: "894148589006335762"   
      compute.googleapis.com/resource_name: "abc20200408180340"   
      compute.googleapis.com/resource_type: "instance"   
      compute.googleapis.com/resource_zone: "us-central1-a"   
     }
     logName: "projects/XXXX/logs/compute.googleapis.com%2Factivity_log"  
     receiveTimestamp: "2020-04-08T18:03:50.816357854Z"  
     resource: {
      labels: {
       instance_id: "894148589006335762"    
       project_id: "XXXX"    
       zone: "us-central1-a"    
      }
      type: "gce_instance"   
     }
     severity: "ERROR"  
     timestamp: "2020-04-08T18:03:50.699874Z"  
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use the Compute Instance Admin (v1) role - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.instanceAdmin.v1  for the beta role, it says you also need roles/iam.serviceAccountUser ... see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.instanceAdmin

Comment: There was an internal issue with Cloud IAM that caused several GCP products to fail. 
You can find more more details in the report [GCP infrastructure incident April 8, 2020](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/zall/20005). Please check your function again.

Comment: Thank you Kolban/Serhii....I have tried "Compute Instance Admin" IAM as well still same issue. And I don't think Cloud IAM internal issue is not the issue hear as it was failing before 04/08.
I have made a small change to the Cloud Function...I have used the default Compute Engine SA( which has Editor role) for Cloud Function and it worked fine...I am not sure why there is a need for Editor role for CF to spin up VM.
Btw, do you advise using default Compute Engine SA for my stuff or should have a new one?

Comment: Could you provide your function to make me able to check it on my own project?